# Setting user values from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to initialize the values in the `User` object but from another question it seems like it's not possible to do it there - now, trying to do the same thing in a view controller in `viewDidLoad`, I'm running into another error:

This is my call to Firebase in `viewDidLoad` (`myUser` is a global variable `var myUser:User!`):

```
        let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").childByAutoId()
        let userRefHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle?

        userRefHandle = userRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            let userData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let id = snapshot.key

            if (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid) != nil {
                if let name = userData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 {
                    let handle = userData["handle"] as! String!
                    let gender = userData["gender"] as! String!
                    let profilePicture = userData["profilePicture"] as! String!
                    let uid = userData["uid"] as! String!
                    // let rooms = userData["rooms"] as! [[String : AnyObject]]

                    myUser.uid = uid
                    myUser.uid = handle
                    myUser.uid = name
                    myUser.uid = profilePicture
                    myUser.uid = gender
//                        myUser.rooms = rooms

                } else {
                    print("Error! Could not initialize User data from Firebase")
                }
            }
        })
```

The end goal for this is so that when a user launches the app (already signed up and their info is in Firebase), their info is pulled from the database and set to the `User` object so the values can be used around the app (name, handle, profilePicture, etc.).

I'm getting the error: `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x106d378c8) to 'NSDictionary'` on the `let userData = snapshot.value` line.

This is what the user's data looks like in Firebase:

```
"users" : {
    "-KgjW9PEvCPVqzn7T5pZ" : {
      "gender" : "male",
      "handle" : "TestHandle123",
      "name" : "Timothy",
      "profilePicture" : "https://graph.facebook.com/*removed*/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1",
      "uid" : "2q4VCKu1e7hiL84ObdzgQcQ0pH63"
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to set a user's values from Firebase, and if so, how to avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you are looking for the profile picture using `profile`

```
let profilePicture = userData["profile"] as! String!
```

but in the data, you have `profilePicture`

Because you have forced the unwrap you will get this error when the key is not found.

You should make sure that you use the same key in both places.  It might also be worth including defaults in case you ever have data issues

```
let profilePicture = userData["profile"] as? String ?? "default"
```

Comment: Good catch, I fixed that but it doesn't affect the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user is already signed up you should store the key that references to the firebase user (e.g. via `NSUserDefaults`). In this case `"-KgjW9PEvCPVqzn7T5pZ"`. Use this in the userRef instead of childByAutoId, which would generate a new child location with a new key and doesn't exists yet (hence the `NSNull`).

```
    let userRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("-KgjW9PEvCPVqzn7T5pZ")
```